# PHP Source Code Showing Up Instead Of What Is Meant To?

Tags: php

I am coding a simple login member system using PHP but each time I go to the PHP page the source code for the page shows up instead of the username and password box. I have this code at the top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

It is right at the top of the page before anything else but when I take that code away the page show up normally but this code appears below the username and password boxes:

```
"; if ($_POST ['loginbtn']){ $user = $_POST['user']; $user = $_POST['password']; if ($user){ if ($password){ echo "$user - $password
$form"; } else echo "you must enter your password $form"; } else echo "you must enter your username $form"; } else echo $form; ?>
```

This code should only be appearing after the user has pressed submit and it shouldn't appear in that form.

Comment: Gonna need to see more code

Comment: Either PHP is not properly setup, or your server doesn't support PHP and is not being parsed, or you're using a file extension other than `.php` --- Show your full code and not just two lines of it.

Comment: @Dagon File extension definitely end with .php.

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine, or via WWW?

Comment: @Fred -ii- local machine.

Comment: accessing via `http://localhost...` not the file directly ?

Comment: Can you/did you try to see if you can echo anything? I.e.: `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>`

Comment: @Dagon I'm accessing through the file directory.

Comment: bingo, then there's no webserver and no php involved

Comment: Hey, you shouted `BINGO` --- See the teller to pick up your prize. @Dagon

Comment: @Fred-ii- picking up the teller IS my prize ;-)

Comment: Make sure "IT" doesn't catch fire this time! ;-) @Dagon

Comment: got to beware of burning bushes, they have made men do strange things in the past.

Comment: and... "kinky" things hehe @Dagon

Answer (score 2):

You clearly have a syntax error somewhere, where something is treated as a string whereas it should be code.

Look for weird syntax coloring in your text editor...

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I agree with @Dagon . Even still, if it's showing up as `code` then obviously it's not wrapped inside proper `<?php` tag. If anything, it would throw a parse error or other type of error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  //this lets php know to start processing
session_start();
?>  // this tells PHP to STOP processing
```

I'm thinking based on what you said that you close your PHP tag and don't open it again for the rest of the code at the bottom.  Instead use:

```
<?php 
session_start();

// rest of php code and page
```

Comment: I do add a new <?php tag after the closing one.

Comment: Oh well, worth a shot; it is impossible to tell with the small code snippet provided.